# Why do we use _ =plt.something in python for ploting in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I saw the use of `_=plt.plot(X,Y)` but `_` is never used, so why do we use it like this and not simply `plt.plot(X,Y)`?

Comment: probably refactored code where the editor was avoiding an unused variable pep8 warning

Comment: Welcome to SO. When writing an answer or a question wrap code by special char, so it will display nicely. See _Code spans_ section in https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This *might* be related to garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is used mainly by people who use to work interactively, for example in an IPython console. In that case IPython would print out the return value of the function call in an output cell. 
If, however, the return is assigned to a variable, no such output occurs. An alternative is to append a `;` after the call.

This is in no way specific to matplotlib.

[image]

Comment: That totally makes sense now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to use the `_`. `_` is used, by convention, when you want to do something but don't really care about the variable it is assigned to. For example if you wanted to do something `x` times but didn't cause about the number of the loop you were on you'd do:

```
for _ in range(x):
    #do this thing x times
```

So I assume whoever wrote that code was just in the habit of writing `_` for this and did it for that too.